# REST API design: how to target property of all resources

Tags: api, rest

Say that we have the following GET:

```
/agents <--returns all agents
/agents/5 <-- returns data for agent id 5
/agents/5/status <-- returns status for agent 5
```

How could I write a RESTful URI to get statuses of all agents? having a /status won't do since other resources also have status. I would like something like:

```
/agents/*/status <-- never seen this
```

but can't find anything similar. Right now I have this:

```
/misc/agentsstatus <-- not pretty
```

**UPDATE**: 
how about this:

```
/agents <--returns all agents
/agents(5) <-- returns data for agent id 5
/agents(5)/status <-- returns status for agent 5
/agents/status <-- returns status for all agents
```

Comment: good genl resource for rest design at http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Answer (score 0):

> How could I write a RESTful URI to get statuses of all agents?

REST doesn't care about spelling -- that's purely a URI design concern.

See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/270898/designing-a-rest-api-by-uri-vs-query-string

If you want the spelling of the URI to communicate semantics to the human reader, you can probably justify

```
/agents?embed=agent.status
```

> A representation of the current agents collection, that includes a representation of the agent status

```
/agents/agent.status
```

> A representation of the current collection of agent.status resources that is subordinate to the current agents collection

```
/agents/digest
```

> A digest representation of the current collection of agents

```
/reports/agentStatusReport
```

> A representation of the current agentStatusReport

Comment: As this seems a common question I was hoping for a more standard convention.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd examples would be problematic at parsing since an agent.id is expected after /agents/.